# API (или что-то подобное) для публикации вопрос/ответ?

Tags: предложение, вопросы, stackoverflow, api

Имеется ли возможность использовать API для работы с сайтом ruSO?

Появилась у меня идея. Я пользователь Linux, и иногда, когда я сталкиваюсь с какой-то проблемой (ошибкой) в консоли, а потом решаю её, то хотелось бы запустить программу (которую, конечно же, я по возможности напишу. Надеюсь, с помощью пользователей ruSO. Скорее всего на Perl), передать ей некоторые данные:

Например, это будет выглядеть так:

```
ruso -q:"Это данные вопроса" -a:"Это ответ на вопрос/решение ошибки" -t:"Метка"
```

Есть ли возможность реализовать такое?

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: @PashaPash а вообще, реально ли такую софтину реализовать? Никаких ограничений не будет, как думаете?

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto есть ограничения.

Answer (score 3):

На само API уже дали ссылку: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Касательно же ограничений, курить это: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle

- If a single IP is making more than 30 requests a second, new requests will be dropped.
- If an application does not have an access_token, then the application shares an IP based quota with all other applications on that IP. This quota is based on the key being passed by the applications; it is the max of the daily request limit for the applications involved, which by default is 10,000. This quota scheme is essentially unchanged from earlier versions of the API.
- If an application does have an access_token, then the application is on a distinct user/app pair daily quota (default size of 10,000). A user can have up to 5 distinct quotas at any one time, though this limit is not reflected in quota_remaining returns for privacy reasons.
- A dynamic throttle is also in place on a per-method level. If an application receives a response with the backoff field set, it must wait that many seconds before hitting the same method again.
- И т.д.

Comment: Всё, понятно! Вопрос можете закрыть и/или удалить))

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto зачем? Может кому-то пригодится.

Comment: Ну тогда можете не закрывать)

Comment: А перевести? :(

Comment: @Qwertiy это к alexolut   (¬‿¬ )

Comment: У меня, говорят, какой-то роботизированный перевод, да ещё и с искажением смысла получается, поэтому воздержусь.

Comment: @alexolut придётся к Aer обращаться.

Comment: @alexolut, про искажение смысла я не говорил... И вообще, надо бы мне дочитать тот пост.

Comment: @Qwertiy он не про вас)

Comment: @Qwertiy про искажение это к КМ замечание, а не к Вам.

Comment: @älёxölüt, это потому что у вас аватарка роботизированная))